# ISO 639 3 (or ISO-639 2) Language Names Translation

Tags: nlp

A part of ISO 639-3 Language Names follows:

```
fan fan fan     I   L   Fang (Equatorial Guinea)    
fao fao fao fo  I   L   Faroese 
fap             I   L   Palor   
far             I   L   Fataleka    
fas per fas fa  M   L   Persian 
fat fat fat     I   L   Fanti   
fau             I   L   Fayu    
fax             I   L   Fala    
fay             I   L   Southwestern Fars   
faz             I   L   Northwestern Fars   
fbl             I   L   West Albay Bikol    
fcs             I   L   Quebec Sign Language
```

Unfortunately language names are written in English only. Is there any translation of ISO-639-3 in other languages and/or native name of each languages?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639%3aa) provided partially such translation in 6 languages+native name.

Is there any active project to provide such database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is:

http://cldr.unicode.org/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLDR

The data is stored in XML files, however, so it may take some processing to extract the data you have in mind.

Comment: Please see:

http://cldr.unicode.org/index/cldr-spec/picking-the-right-language-code

The default in CLDR, as I understand it, is to use a two-letter code if one exists (en, es, de…), and a three-letter code otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that is just cover live languages and not extinct ones

Comment: That’s true. Is there a specific list of extinct languages you need translated?  If you’re looking for a complete multilingual list of extinct languages I’m not sure that such a thing exists.